# Python counting string

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have to define a function called `letterCount` in which it returns an integer for the number of times there is a string in the function.  For some reason, it returns `2` and I am supposed to return `7`

```
def letterCount(text,collection):
    for collection in text:
        if collection in text:
           return len(collection) + 1
seuss = 'The cat in a hat came back'
letters = 'ac'
print(letterCount(seuss,letters))
```

Comment: It looks to me like your function does not `return` anything at all.

Comment: Also, I think that your indentation is still not correct. The last line is not part of your function is it?

Comment: `for collection in text...if collection in text` is kind of redundant.

Comment: Your function returns 2 because this `if collection in text:` of course is True so it returns `len(collection) + 1` on the first iteration

Comment: You're also redefining `collection` in your function. You start off with `collection` being "ac" but then, when you do your `for` loop, collection becomes "T" (i.e. the first letter in your sentence).

Comment: Check out this resource:  http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#.  It will execute your code step by step and show you the value of every variable along the way.  I found it extremely helpful when I was starting out (and still sometimes today!)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want this:

```
def letterCount(text,collection):
    res = 0
    for c in text:
        if c in collection:
            res = res + 1
    return res
seuss = 'The cat in a hat came back'
letters = 'ac'
print(letterCount(seuss,letters))
```

you define an variable `collection` in `for collection in text:`, it hidden the variable in `def letterCount(text,collection)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of times the string `letters` occurs in `seuss`:

```
def letterCount(text,collection):
    count = 0

    for i in range(0, len(text) - len(collection)):
        if collection == text[i:i + len(collection)]:
            count += 1

    return count

seuss = 'The cat in a hat came back'
letters = 'ac'
print(letterCount(seuss,letters))
```

If you want to count the number of times each letter in `letters` occurs in `seuss`:

```
def letterCount(text,collection):
    count = 0

    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        for c in collection:       
            if c == text[i]:
                count += 1

    return count

seuss = 'The cat in a hat came back'
letters = 'ac'
print(letterCount(seuss,letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax of the python code you wrote is wrong. this is most probably what you want

```
def letterCount(text,collection):
  for collection in text:
    if collection in text:
        return len(collection) + 1
seuss = 'The cat in a hat came back'
Letters = 'ac'
print(letterCount(seuss,Letters))
```

your question is also not clear. can you elaborate a little. if what you want is to count the number of words in the string
this would suffice

```
print len(seuss.split(' '))
```

Comment: I think he wants to count the number of times the letters "a" or "c" appear in his text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count the number of letters in the sentence, I'd do this:

```
def letterCount(text,collection):
  lettercount = 0
  for letter in collection:
    lettercount += text.count(letter)
  return lettercount


seuss = 'The cat in a hat came back'
Letters = 'ac'
print(letterCount(seuss,Letters)) # Returns 8
```

Explanation:

`lettercount = 0` sets our counter to 0

`for letter in collection:` creates a loop through the list of the letters you passed to the function. In this case "a" and "c"

`lettercount += text.count(letter)` counts the number of times each letter appears in the sentence and adds it to the counter.

`return lettercount` sends the result back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
def letterCount(text,collection):
    return sum(len(re.findall(c, text)) for c in collection)

# re.findall(c, text) -> find all occurences of letter c in text
# len(...)            -> get the length of the list of all occurrences of c in text
# sum(...)            -> sum up all the partial results
```

Comment: I'll try to comment it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the number of times either 'a' or 'c' comes in 'The cat in a hat came back', then:

```
import collections
def letter_count(text, letters):
    counter = collections.Counter(text)
    return sum(counter.get(letter, 0) for letter in letters)
```